# When is a multivariate cubic polynomial mapping $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$ both one-to-one and onto?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, roots, real-algebraic-geometry, multivariate-polynomial

In one dimension, a cubic polynomial mapping $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$

$$y = A + Bx + Cx^2 + Dx^3$$

is one-to-one and onto when its derivative $y'(x) = B + 2Cx + 3Dx^2$ has less than two zeros, i.e., $4C^2 - 12BD \leq 0$. Then $y(x)$ is monotonic almost everywhere, one-to-one, and onto.

How do things work for $\Bbb{R^n}$ to $\Bbb{R^n}$? Suppose (after some coordinate transformation)

$$y_i = x_i + \sum_{jk} A_{ijk} x_j x_k + \sum_{jkm} B_{ijkm} x_j x_k x_m$$

It's easy to take the Jacobian, but what is the precise condition for $y(x)$ to be one-to-one and onto from $\Bbb{R^n}$ to $\Bbb{R^n}$?

I have a guess, but I imagine this is a pretty well-known result in algebraic geometry. A source would also be appreciated.

Comment: This is not quite the same thing as but related to the Jacobian conjecture which is a famous open problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture

Comment: Thank you; that's a fascinating conjecture, which I had never heard of! Fortunately for my purposes, this is much simpler (degree 3 and the inverse is not expected to be polynomial).